# Mongodb. Cannot find defined collection in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am experiencing quite a strange issue. I have a mongodb and i connect to it through c# driver. I define a collection using some gui mongo client like robomongo. But for some reason i cannot see the collection in c#, even though it is seen anywhere else (other gui clients, php).

I am using same users everywhere.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you add more details, including: how are you attempting to "see" the collection in C#? What is the DB name you're using to connect to using the GUI and what is it when you're using the connection string?

Comment: Gonna need to see some code to help you

Comment: Could you add the connection string you are using in PHP/other clients, and the one you are using in C#? What you are describing is theoretically impossible

Answer (score -1):

You must add a Class

like code  below

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("testdb"); // "testdb" is the name of the database

// "Users" is the name of the collection
var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("Users");
// var searchQuery = Query.EQ("firstname", "Tom"); 
var cursor = collection.FindAll();
```

what is Entity?
-It's the class i'm telling yout about to get and set fields inside this collection.

In my case,it should look like this :

```
class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```